# Separate first letter from String for capitalization

Tags: java, string, split, capitalization

I want to take a String input form a user, and format it so that the first letter is capitalized and the rest is not. I would like to do this by splitting the first letter from the string and use `.toUpperCase()` on it and use `.toLowerCase()` on the rest, and then merge them back together.

I have an idea, but can't solve everything:

```
userInput = input.nextLine();
String firstLetter = ???
firstLetter.toUpperCase();
restOfString.toLowerCase();
String merged = firstLetter + restOfString;
```

This does NOT seem to work:

```
            name = input.nextLine();
            firstLetter = name.substring(0,1);
            remainingString = name.substring(1);
            firstLetter.toUpperCase();
            remainingString.toLowerCase();
            name = firstLetter + remainingString;
```

Comment: As I noted in my answer, you have to assign `firstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase();` String methods return a new String with the values changed. They don't update the original String.

Comment: Oh, i see. Sorry, i missed that! Aand it works! Thank you!! :)

Comment: This was a duplicate when it was asked yesterday.  Probably still is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use substring.

```
String firstLetter = userInput.substring(0,1); //takes first letter
String restOfString = userInput.substring(1); //takes rest of sentence
firstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase(); //make sure to set the string, the methods return strings, they don't change the string itself
restOfString = restOfString.toLowerCase();
String merged = firstletter + restOfString;
```

*Edit*: If you wish to do error-checking on the user's input:

```
if(userInput.length < 2) {
    throw new InputMismatchException("Sentence too short to properly capitalize!";
}
```

Comment: Two error checks: The string needs one letter for `.substring(0, 1)` to work, and it needs two letters for `.substring(1)` to work.  Depending on our specific use, it may not matter.

Comment: @BrianJ I've added error handling as an aside at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are using Java based on `toUpperCase()`. What I would suggest you do, is use `charAt()` to get the first letter, and substring to get the rest.

You can try something like this:

```
String firstLetter = userInput.substring(0, 1); // Get first element. If you don't understand substring, let me know.
string remainingString = userInput.substring(1); // Grab chars from index 1 to the end.

firstLetter.toUpperCase(); // Capitalize string
remainingString.toLowerCase(); // Lowercase rest of string

String finalString = firstLetter + remainingString;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, looks very good! I do get 1 error at the "CharAt(0)" though.. Incompatible types: char cannot be converted to java.lang.string - Do you know why? :) do i have to import any packages to do this?

Comment: @CasperTL no, I think that is my fault. Perhaps char cannot be converted, I will adjust my answer to use substring.

Comment: Thanks for your time! i got it to work with the answer by Compass though (via substrings) :)

Comment: Fair enough, answers are the same. First come first serve I suppose! Feel free to ask if you have any other questions.